# Move chapter preamble before Chapter headline

Tags: koma-script, scrbook

I would like to insert silly quotes before the chapter headline. I am using scrbook / KOMAScript -- unfortunately in version 3.17a (texlive 2015).

I would also like to insert a rule below the chapter headline.

This is a small example:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scrhack}

\begin{document}

\setchapterpreamble{
\begin{flushright}
MySillyQuote
\end{flushright}}

\chapter{MyChapter}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

What I would like to have is something like this:

[image: The Goal]

The preamble should be moved up (red) and there should be a line (highlighted in green, but should be regular black).
Only chapters that have chapter-prefixes have chapter-preambles in my document and those chapters without prefixes should not reserve extra space for a preamble. For the remaining chapters it would be OK to hard-code the space for the chapter-preamble to e.g. 3 lines (although dynamic fit would obviously be preferable).

I have tried a few things using `\chapterformat` but they don't seem to work, because my KOMAScript is too old.

EDIT: no longer interested in the rule.

Comment: If memory serves (can't test now): `\setchapterpreamble[o]{...}`?

Comment: That was a lot easier than I had expected, I should have just RTFM. Thanks! I can even add a box above and below. However, if I add the box below with a `\rule` there is too much spacing between headline and rule... anyway to change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment by @campa indicated `[o]` is sufficient to move the preamble up. Also `\dictum` helps with the quote:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scrhack}

\begin{document}

\setchapterpreamble[o]{
\dictum[Author]{quote}}

\chapter{MyChapter}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

I have decided to not add the bar below for now and will open a separate question if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As an answer to the general question there is the `epigraph` package that can be used with any class which enables an epigraph (silly quote) to be inserted wherever in the document. Here is an example of putting an epigraph before a chapter title:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Celestial navigation}
\epigraphhead[70]{\epigraph{Star crossed lovers.}{\textit{The Bard}}}
% ...
```

To put the epigraph after the chapter title don't use `\epigraphhead` simply

```
\chapter*{Celestial navigation}
\epigraph{Star crossed lovers.}{\textit{The Bard}}
```